# What to use for a datagrid with a lot of data?

Tags: asp.net, xml, datagrid, datareader

Found this interesting interview question:

You need to display the sales data for your division for the past 5 years in a DataGrid on a Web Form. Performance is very important. What would be the best strategy to use in retrieving the data?

- a)Use a DataReader object to retrieve
  the data for the DataGrid.
- b)Use a DataSet object to retrieve the
  data for the DataGrid.
- c)Use a simple select statement as the
  data source for the DataGrid.
- d)Use a cached XML file as the data
  source and retrieve the data with a
  DataSet.

My answer is c) but I am not too sure
Can anyone point me to the right answer and explain it to me please
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically any time a test mentions performance and DataReader and DataSet, the rule of thumb is DataReader == fast and DataSet == slow.

Comment: Personally my answer would be "Buy a grid control that does server-side paging if it's that important"

Answer (score 3):

I'd use [paging](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020135845/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/091003-1.aspx).

You can also accomplish this [using stored procedures](https://web.archive.org/web/20210619184031/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/062899-1.shtml).

Comment: Yes, this is the right way to do it, IMO. +1 but I'm out of votes :[

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably say choice A of the answers provided, but paging is definitely the more correct answer. DataSets are slow and load the whole table while DataReader is really fast, just iterating over the records.

Using a select statement as the datasource is just bad practice and never recommended.

Answer (score 0):

1. If performance is very important then don't use a datagrid, use a repeater or an ordinary loop.
2. I would assume a cached XML file (memomry) is faster than retrieving data from a database BUT could also use a considerable amount of memory, so not the right answer I think.
3. A select statement and a DataReader is very much alike, but you have some more out-of-the-box features with a DataReader, so that would be my answer.

Comment: How do you even execute a select statement on a database in .net without a DataReader or DataAdapter?